# How to apply a formula to cells when data is entered in the same cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to solve a problem in excel where, data is received and pasted in cells (actually, whole sheet is copy pasted), I want to apply some logic to the data in some adjacent rows.

For example this is a scenario
When the data is copied into row 2 and row 3, I want to merge the two rows and delete the row tagged with "Merge-Delete".

[image]

I am sure it is easily possible in VBA, but I am trying to find a solution in the form of Excel formulas to merge the two records. The merge logic is, to fill in the cells of "Merge-Delete" until the first non-empty record in "Merge" row, and calculate the new average for data and result.

[image]

I have tried to use self referencing cells but could not figure out how to deal with this problem. I understand the problem has multiple issues but I am trying to figure out how to merge the data first. The rows are not always 2 and not always in this order. However, there is only one row that is tagged "Merge" and rest of them are "Merge-Delete".

Is there any way I can apply some formula/logic to merge the rows upon data insertion?

Comment: You can't do it, because it will be circular, except you put the formula in other row or you use VBA.  For formula, you must have two formulas, for data and for result

Comment: Use a helper sheet and paste the data there. in your main sheet keep only "merge" row which will have the formula